# iterate over a map and calling a function that deletes other elements is the map

Tags: c++, stl

i have a map which is defined in global memory.
i'm iterating over it, let's say i'm in the 3rd element. now i'm calling another function that generates its own iterator over the same map, however it might erase the 4th or 5th ... elements in the map.
my question is, when i return from that function and continue to iterate over the map (i remind you i'm in the 3rd element), can my iterator be invalid or is it safe?

sorry i can't attach the code it is very very long.

thanks

EDIT:
my question is something like this:

```
map<string,string> mapi;

void er() {
    mapi.erase("t");
} 

int main() {


mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("w","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("e","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("r","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("t","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("A","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("u","a"));
mapi.insert(pair<string,string>("C","a"));

map<string,string>::iterator it;
for (it=mapi.begin(); it!=mapi.end(); it++) {
    cout << it->first << endl;
    if (it->first=="t")
        er();
}
```

}

in this case i erase the same element - valgrind says its an error. however when i delete other elements it seems to work fine.

Comment: Create a simple use-case and test it.

Comment: @Xeo: That would not *guarantee* that it's safe and defined.

Comment: i created somthing very simple. seems to work however i just want others opinion just to be sure

Comment: @Oli: But it would at least give some indication of success or failure, which could be used to refine the question. :)

Comment: @rob: Then say that you did so and maybe include the code. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I don't think such an experiment would really add to the question; the issue here (paraphrasing) is whether the standard guarantees such behaviour...

Comment: included an example. any idea anyone?

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html:

> Erasing an element from a map also
>   does not invalidate any iterators,
>   except, of course, for iterators that
>   actually point to the element that is
>   being erased.

Comment: If you do erase the current element the return value gives you a new valid iterator to continue from (instead of incrementing the invalidated iterator which gives undefined behaviour). It's sometimes possible to re-arrange the loop to make use of this.

Comment: erase() in map is void. no iterator is returned

Comment: @rob You're right; I was thinking of the sequence requirements. For map `m.erase(i++)` can do the trick (one of the few good uses for post-increment).